Laravel 11 images do not appear when deployed online, but they do appear when running locally
This issue occurs when I am running the application locally.
running on localhost
This issue occurs when I am running the application online.
running online
However, I am accessing both at the same time, and I have checked the database to confirm that the images are saved in the public/storage folder.
I am using Laravel 11 and Cloudflare to deploy it.
Please help me.
I want the images to appear when online / when deployed.

Have you checked the browser's developer console and/or the network tab to see what it's trying to access and what the error is? Have you confirmed that the images it's looking for are in the path that it's requesting? Can you access the images directly in the browser? There really isn't enough information here to know what's going on, and you'll need to do a lot of troubleshooting to get more information.
